# how to get static block content custom attributes by block id in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I am creating this below block content in admin HTML. I cant able to get the slidertype attributes in **3columns.phtml** but in template page i can get

```
$this->getData('slidertype').
```

So kindly give the solution that how to get the following attributes.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_bestseller" name="bestseller" slidercount="20" slidertype="1" template="catalog/product/bestseller_right.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the below code to get static block attribute value. Its working fine for us.

```
$bestSellerBlock = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
 ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
 ->load("best_seller");

$bestSellerContentText  =   strip_tags($bestSellerBlock->getContent());
preg_match('/slidertype="(.*?)"/u',$bestSellerContentText,$sliderTypeArray);
$sliderType =   trim($sliderTypeArray[1]);
```

Thanks,
Arularasan D.